# HTACCESS - Serve 404 for "deny from" instead of 403 for files to an ipaddress

Tags: security, htaccess, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to serve `404` instead of `403` when matched with "`deny from`"?

For **example**:

```
<Files *>
order deny,allow

deny from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

This will normally server a 403. But I want to server 404.

Comment: What is the reason for this?  It may help come up with a better solution to know your reasoning.

Comment: Because I want to not even let them know that the content actually exists ! if a miscreant behind the blocked IP sees its 403, you can only imagine his motivations are going up..

Answer (score 2):

You can be proactive about returning 404s if you know which files will 403:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ".*\/\..*"
```

will return a `404` for all files which start with a `.`, such as `.htaccess`. I don't think this will serve as a global "transform all `403`s into `404`s", however.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486304/is-there-a-way-to-force-apache-to-return-404-instead-of-403
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548156/problem-redirecting-403-forbidden-to-404-not-found

Comment: Thanks but this is very specific to details. And my question is related to `deny from ip`. How to put both of these things together?

Comment: @RaheelHasan If you have specific IPs you want to do a global block against (`<Files *>` -> `deny from <IP>`), then you should be dropping the packets at the firewall (`iptables -A INPUT --s <IP> -j DROP`) so that they can't even touch the webserver. If you want to be specific about only `403`s, then you might need to run some sort of proxy in front of apache.

Comment: You could proxy the apache server with `nginx` and then configure `nginx` with `proxy_intercept_errors on;` and `error_page 403 =404;` when the requests come from the appropriate IPs

Comment: I like your ideas.. but I am on a shared hosting, so cant do all those things.... but thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it is in the backend code.

On my system, access to downloadable files is done via one particular php file.  This creates a page with a link that expires after a few minutes.  For me, it would be easy.

If you have a backend, where access to files is routed via one or more files then you can check the ipaddress in there and raise 404.